# View Source: JSON Response is showing instead of HTML source code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, laravel

So, when I view my page source, the json response (aka the table i'm retrieving) is showed instead of the html page.

I've been trying to figure out at first how to retrieve a json response while still rendering the HTML, which had me to come up with this controller code. Would like to help on how to improve my code to solve this problem. Would appreciate suggestions!

My controller:

```
$products = Product::all();
    if (\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::ajax())
      return response()->json($products);
    else
      return view('products.index');
```

Jquery Script:

```
$(document).ready( function () {

var pathname = window.location.pathname;


  loadProducts();

function loadProducts(){
var columns = [{
        "sTitle": "Name",
        "mData": "name"
    }, {
        "sTitle": "Price",
        "mData": "price"
    }, {
        "sTitle": "Category_ID",
        "mData": "category_id"
    }, {
        "sTitle": "Supplier_ID",
        "mData": "supplier_id"
    }]

$.ajax({
    'url': '{{ url('products') }}',
    'method': "GET",
    'contentType': 'application/json'
}).done( function(data) {
      var example_table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
        "aaData": data,
        "columns": columns
      });
 });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) [JSONP data source for remote domains](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/jsonp.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "scripts/jsonp.php",
            "dataType": "jsonp"
        }
    } );
} );
```